# Redis in docker container with custom file redis.conf doesn't work

Tags: docker, redis

I want to set up master-slave redis in docker container; And I want to use redis.conf in slave's container;

Test environment :win7+Docker Quickstart Terminal;

Before start,Create three file redis-6379、redis-6380、redis-6381 to this path: '~/Desktop/redis/';Then create redis.conf foreach file;(Using the official configuration);Then use Docker Quickstart run command :

```
cp -rf ~/Desktop/redis/ /usr/local/
```

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f4QB.png)
[content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIV8U.png)

I do this in the fllowing steps:

1、modify redis.conf (redis-6381/redis-6380)

`slaveof 172.17.0.2 6379`

2、specify this redis.conf

```
docker run -v /usr/local/redis/redis-6381/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name redis-6381 -p 6381:6379 -d redis redis-server  /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

docker logs gives me: Configuration loaded;Actually redis.conf has no effect;
info replication show,this redis still be a master role;

Then,I tried in this way,it works:

```
docker run --name redis-6381 -p 6381:6379 -d redis redis-server slaveof 172.17.0.2 6379
```

So,why redis.conf cann't work ?

Comment: Get inside the container and see if `/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf` has the `slaveof` value or not?

Comment: '/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf' is empty;

Comment: That means `/usr/local/redis/redis-6381/redis.conf` on your host machine doesn't exists

Comment: that's the problem;I use command 'vim /usr/local/redis/redis-6381/redis.conf` on my host machine;this file exitsts, content correct;

Comment: What are you using? Docker for mac ? Add your infrastructure details

Comment: I added more detailed operation to my question; thank you very much;

Comment: After `cp -rf ~/Desktop/redis/ /usr/local/` check the contents of `/usr/local`? Are all the files there?

Comment: All checked ;I add two picture to question;file and content

Comment: Can you try `-v ~/Desktop/redis/redis-6381/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf` instead from `/usr/local`

Comment: Thanks, Success!  So win7 file must be used instead of Linux（VirtualBox )  is the cause of this issue ; Why can't I use linux file with command `cp -rf ~/Desktop/redis/ /usr/local/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `-v ~/Desktop/redis/redis-6381/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/r‌​edis.conf` instead from /usr/local`

The problem is that when you work on Windows, Docker will automatically share some of your Drives to the VM in which docker runs. So your paths will work.

But MingW may be hosting the `/usr/local` folder somewhere else and showing it to you mounted at `/usr/`. I don't use windows, so can't confirm that for you.

When you use `-v /usr/local/redis/redis-6381/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf` the host path doesn't translate insider docker and hence a blank file is created and mapped.